# Вопрос по 2 колонкам в ListView Android

Tags: android, listview

Есть ListView, планируется сделать в нём 2 колонки. Первое значение в списке будет добавляться по кнопке пользователем, а второе значение будет браться из сети(всего 2 возможных значения: 0 или 1). Для первого столбца используется ArrayAdapter(добавление строки по кнопке пользователем), а как построить 2 колонку - не могу определиться. Нашёл реализацию через HashMap и Cursos, но, мне кажется, что это не самая удобная реализация, учитывая, что 2 колонка будет браться и проверяться из сети. Подскажите, пожалуйста, возможную реализацию этого, желательно через ArrayAdapter.

Comment: Проще написать свой адаптер.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ListView повторяет определенную разметку с разными данными несколько раз (разметка совершенно любая, какая угодно).

Соответственно, у этой разметки может быть левая и правая часть, которые при веритикальном повторении будут образрвывать нечто вроде таблицы с двумя столбцами.

Вот адаптер, который заполняет нужные поля в элементах списка. Копирую его из проекта в проект. На вход принимается список данных. `R.layout.element_layout` - разметка одного элемента.

```
public class SearchResultAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<DataObj> {

    public SearchResultAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<DataObj> dataList) {
        super(context, 0, dataList);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        DataObj data = getItem(position);
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.element_layout, parent, false);
        }

        TextView column1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.col1);
        TextView column2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.col2);


        column1.setText(data.field1);
        column2.setText(data.field2);


        return convertView;
    }
}
```

`DataObj` - класс, имеющий все поля, необходимые для отображения одной строки `ListView`. В методе `getView` эти поля используются для формирования его визуального интерфейса.

**EDIT:** **Использование**

В `Activity`:

```
private SearchResultAdapter adapter; 
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    adapter = new SearchResultAdapter(this, list);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); 
}
```

`list` - ArrayList из нужных вам элементов. В качестве элементов могут использоватся как Integer и String, так и более сложные объекты.

Далее измените метод `getView(...)` так, чтобы все элементы интерфейса заполнились данными из переданного объекта.

**Для того, чтобы обновить `ListView`(если вы изменили элементы списка `ArrayList`), используйте `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`**

Comment: Можно попросить у Вас пример кода, где используется этот адаптер или немного пояснений, т.к. никак не получается его внедрить..

Comment: @DenisMolodec посмотрите дополненный ответ.

Comment: в этом месте всё ясно. Немного не понятно с DataObj и DataList. Никогда раньше это не использовал. Подскажите или ткните носом, где подробно описано..

Comment: DataObj это созданный вами кастомный класс со всеми данными, необходимыми для отображения одной строки списка (таблицы)

Comment: Благодарю! И правда универсальный адаптер! Всё прекрасно заработало